When OData apply ODataQueryOptions<T> in .NET 8?
Help me understand when Odata applies query parameters to IQueryable?
The task is as follows: it is necessary to get the result of the query execution to the database before sending it to the client.
I use .NET 8.0 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 9.0.0
I try the classic implementation of applying queryOptions via .ApplyTo(IQueryable query) but I get a result that I don't quite need - SelectSome<T>. I'd like to get json or cast result to Product
[HttpGet("get")]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Product> queryOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var resultQuery = (IQueryable<dynamic>) queryOptions.ApplyTo(dbContext.Products.AsQueryable());
    var result = await resultQuery.ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    //some other actions
    return Ok(result);
}

I also try to use IActionFilter but no success.
[Route("odata/Products")]
[Authorize]
public class ProductsOdataController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet("get")]
    [EnableQuery]
    [OdataResultFilter]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(dbContext.Products.AsQueryable());
    }
}

public class OdataResultFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectResult.Value);
            
        objectResult.Value = json;
    }
}

When I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectResult.Value) I'm getting data from Product but without OData parameters.
I got one more variant to use .Cast<ISelectExpandWrapper>()
[HttpGet("get")]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<CrmContractor> queryOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var resultQuery = queryOptions.ApplyTo(dbContext.CrmContractors.AsQueryable()).Cast<ISelectExpandWrapper>();
    var result = await resultQuery.Select(wrapper => wrapper.ToDictionary()).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    
    //some other actions
    return Ok(result);
}

I get List<IDictionary<string,object>> and can work with it, but if I use $expand like this
https://localhost/odata/Products?$expand=Orders

I will get one of KeyValuePair like this
KeyValuePair<string,object>() {
    Key = "Orders",
    Value = List<SelectSome<Order>>...
}

What am I doing wrong?

See: https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData/pull/824

Can you create a minimal sample to reproduce the problem and share it? According to your code and the official doc Applying query options directly and SelectExpand query, I create a sample to test it and get the same result with the official sample, you can check it.

Yes, I can make an example in a few days when I return to work. @ZhiLv

I have added a small example :

get1 - classic implementation;
get2 - working without $selet or $expand
get3 - working only $select


Based on your example, since you have already installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.NewtonsoftJson package and register the related NewtonsoftJson services in the program.cs file.
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddODataNewtonsoftJson()
    .AddOData(options =>
    {
        options.EnableQueryFeatures()
            .AddRouteComponents("odata", GetEdmModel());
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });

In the action method, you can cast the result to an object type, try to modify the method as below:
[HttpGet("get3")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get3(ODataQueryOptions<Product> options)
{
    IQueryable<object> result;
    if (this.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue) 
        result = options.SelectExpand.ApplyTo(context.Products.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable(), new ODataQuerySettings()).Cast<object>();  
    else 
        result = options.ApplyTo(context.Products.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable(), new ODataQuerySettings()).Cast<object>(); 
    return Ok(result.ToList());
}

Then, the result like this:


Yes, it works in response, but result.ToList() returns a type of SelectSome<T>, so I can't serialize this result to JSON or cast it to the Product class.

@Uladzimir This seems is a known issue, you can check Support in memory filtering after ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo and How convert result from ApplyTo to IQueryable
